# KNN converging to regression function proof (ESL page 19)

Tags: k-nearest-neighbour, statistical-learning

In Elements of Statistical Learning, page 19, it says [image]

I am confused what it means by "under mild regularity condition" and how one can prove the statement $\hat{f}(x) \rightarrow E(Y|X = x)$ under the given conditions. Could anyone point me to resource for the proof?